# I need to find top 2 most frequently occurring device_id and how many time they occur

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXus5.png)

I want to find top 2 most frequently occurring device ids with their counts.

```
device_id       count 

32145678665     3

3214567866555   4
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`. And if that doesn't solve your problem, ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only really answering because it is slightly more tricky than simply using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT device_id , COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY device_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
WHERE rownum <=2
```

The subquery (inline view) will find all device_ids and how often they come up as well as order them from most frequent to least frequent.

Then we can just query from there and keep only the two most frequent rows by using the pseudocolumn `ROWNUM`

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 2 DEVICEID,COUNT(DEVICEID) as CountOfDevice from yourtable
group by DEVICEID
order by COUNT(DEVICEID) DESC
```